# what is Nhibernate CurrentContext

Tags: .net, nhibernate

what is the purpose of `CurrentSessionContext.Bind( sessionFactory.OpenSession());` in the nhibernate.

```
public void Application_Start()
{

    BeginRequest += delegate 
 {

        CurrentSessionContext.Bind( sessionFactory.OpenSession());    

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the [contextual session](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session).

In general web projects (it can be done on onther plataforms too), it is a commom pratice to have a `ISession` defined on the request context, between the `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` events. So, when you define a bind of a session, you can access it from the `SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` method on your data access layer, without managing all the connections with databases and keeping it managed on the high layer (UI).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How can we access the sessionfactory defined in global.asax from Data access Layer. I want to access global.asax from another class library(services prject)

Comment: I want it like this in my service project;                                                                                                public class MyService : IMyService
 {
   public void doStuff()
   {
      ISession session = Global.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

   }
}

Comment: Look for implementations called session per request http://benfoster.io/blog/yet-another-session-per-request-post